# Livewire, Laravel - can I call a controller 'store' method from a Livewire component?

Tags: laravel, methods, laravel-livewire

I have a Laravel controller with a 'store' method. i.e. store(Request $request).

For the view I want to embed a livewire component and then utilize the existing controller 'store' method (behind the scenes) from a livewire component method. Is this possible? Currently, I'm running into the problem that there is no Request object since I'm no longer making the call from the existing route/view (i.e. POST /orders).

```
public function oms_order()
// this method provides the POST /orders leveraging 
// Controllers\OrderController@store
{
    $this->refId = app('App\Http\Controllers\OrderController')->store($this->jsonOrder);
}
```

**Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::store() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\jade\livewire_hpp\app\Http\Livewire\Oms.php on line 26**

I can remove the 'Request $request' from the store method but then that breaks the standard Laravel POST /orders route.

I was hoping to use the existing laravel app as the backend/API and add the livewire bit for a demo. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: try `store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $this->jsonOrder);`

Comment: try `app(OrderController::class)->store(request(), $this->jsonOrder)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a best practice to call a controller function from another class. If you want reusability, I suggest refactoring code by creating a separate class with a store method which accepts only required attributes and saves a record.
Then you can use this method in multiple places. It is easier to test also.
It is difficult to give an exact answer before seeing your store method.

Answer (score 0):

oh man! , you should change your naming conventions , write the full name of the function , if you write the code correctly no need to write comments like this it's just one line code!

make a trait or helper function to do tasks between classes this is the best practice . controller is a part of MVC logic so, separation is required then if you do logic frequently just separate it in trait the use it in other classes